# Can I remove mapStateToProps from my component having only mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I don't need mapStateToProps in my component but I need mapDispatchToProps -

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
    ({
        myCallBack(passFunc, passDirFunc) {
            dispatch(
                actions.setSideNavAction(passFunc, passDirFunc)
            )
        }
    })
```

If I remove mapStateToProps completely and use connect like -

```
export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(Application);
```

then getting error -  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dispatch is not a function.

Is it mandatory to keep an empty mapStateToProps.

```
const mapStateToProps = state =>
    ({

    })
```

Please clarify .

Comment: if mapStateToProps is falsy, the Connect component doesn't subscribe to store state changes.

Answer (score 62):

You can just pass a `null` to the `connect`:

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Application);
```